# get full User object on post_save signal

Tags: django

I am new to signals. What I want to do could be done on views pragmatically and perhaps signals is not the way to go but regardless, I am having issues with the signal. I have a User model (custom) and UserIdentities model. When a new user is created, 3 identities will be generated and saved in UserIdentities model:

```
     User(models.Model):
      fields...

     UserIdentities(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @receiver(post_save, sender = User)
    def user_created(sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
         if created:
             # generate three dept identities and save in UserIdentities model
             identities = generate_identiteies(instance)
```

The issue I am having now is that instance is username (a single string), not an instance of User object with all attributes of the user. In the documentation, it says instance is the object that was created but here I am getting only the username of the user created but need a couple of other fields needed for identity generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue I am having now is that instance is username...I am getting only the username of the user created...

This should not be the case. The `instance` in case of `post_save` is the actual instance which was `save`d.

You can verify this by putting `assertIsInstance(instance, User.class)` before `if created` statement in your signal method. If you do not get `AssertionError`, you can safely assume that `instance` is not a string.